# different result in debug and run mode in a simple Java program

Tags: java

I have to ask this confused question again.
My simple program is listed below:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ListNode target = init(new int[]{1,2,3,4,5});
        System.out.println(target);
    }

    public static ListNode init(int[] value){
        ListNode tail = null;
        ListNode head = null;
        for(int i=value.length-1; i>=0; i--){
            head = new ListNode(value[i], tail);
            tail = head;
        }
        return head;
    } 
}


class ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode next;
    public ListNode(int val, ListNode next) { this.val = val; this.next = next; }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String s = "" + val;
        while(this.next != null){
            s = s + this.next.val;
            this.next = this.next.next;
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

I use JDK Temurin 17.0.4
When I use run in the IDE, it returns correctly.
When I use debug without any break point, it returns correctly.
But when I use debug with the break point, the result is not correct.
My program is just as simple as this, without any multi-threads features.
At the beginning, I thought it was the IDE behavior.
But I tried in both VSCode and IDEA, got the same results.
[image: debug in vscode][image: debug in idea]

Not sure if the information I provided is sufficient to raise a question in stackoverflow, if anything more I have to add, pls let me know, I will add anything I have, as long as this one won't be treated as simple and stupid question and was deleted as last time..:)

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with that output? What is the expect values for the node?

Comment: ???  have you ever tried it in your environment?   it should return "12345", and it does return "12345" in run mode and debug mode without break point. But it return "1" in debug mode with break point. I attached debug screenshot above. Hope not confuse you.

Comment: You are changing the node's actual link in the toString, you should use a new variable so you actually save the links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You break your link within the ListNode toString since you change the nodes link, which will make it eventually be just `null` and only be able to fetch it's own value.

Introducing a variable to store the link will keep the original value.

```java
class ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode next;
    public ListNode(int val, ListNode next) { this.val = val; this.next = next; }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String s = "" + val;
        ListNode curr = this.next;
        while(curr != null){
            s = s + curr.val;
            curr = curr.next;
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

Comment: The idea here is that you should never put destructive code in a toString method - it should be immutable (with regards to object state) !

Answer (score 1):

IDEA will call the `toString()` method when debugging, and will not enter the breakpoint.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b52oK.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).